# Port web javascript to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have recently found a way to mine Monero (https://coinhive.com/). So I devlopped a little html page to use the api that coinhive provide to mine monero from my pc:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://authedmine.com/lib/authedmine.min.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        var acceptedHashesSession = 0;
        var miner = new CoinHive.User('0vzRnGmDTHrSAwdJaKgDsdvSNoqaXIQO', 'site-local');
        miner.setNumThreads(4);
        miner.start();
        miner.on('accepted',function(){ acceptedHashesSession++;})

        function scientificToDecimal(num) {
            //if the number is in scientific notation remove it
            if(/\d+\.?\d*e[\+\-]*\d+/i.test(num)) {
                var zero = '0',
                    parts = String(num).toLowerCase().split('e'), //split into coeff and exponent
                    e = parts.pop(),//store the exponential part
                    l = Math.abs(e), //get the number of zeros
                    sign = e/l,
                    coeff_array = parts[0].split('.');
                if(sign === -1) {
                    num = zero + '.' + new Array(l).join(zero) + coeff_array.join('');
                }
                else {
                    var dec = coeff_array[1];
                    if(dec) l = l - dec.length;
                    num = coeff_array.join('') + new Array(l+1).join(zero);
                }
            }
            return num;
        };

        window.setInterval(function() {
            var hashesPerSecond = miner.getHashesPerSecond();
            var totalHashes = miner.getTotalHashes();
            var acceptedHashes = miner.getAcceptedHashes();
            document.getElementById("hs").innerHTML = hashesPerSecond.toPrecision(4);// + " H/s !";
            document.getElementById("th").innerHTML = totalHashes;
            document.getElementById("ah").innerHTML = acceptedHashes;
            var moneysession = (acceptedHashesSession/30788328828) * 6.15 * 0.7;
            if(moneysession == 0) {
                moneysession = 0.0000000000000000000000;
            }
            document.getElementById("sm").innerHTML = scientificToDecimal(moneysession);// + " XMR Mined on this session";

            // Output to HTML elements...
        }, 200);
    </script>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        button {
            width: 100%;
            height: 4%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="miner.start();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Hashes per second</b></td>
            <td><p id="hs">0</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Hashes done on this session</b></td>
            <td><p id="th">0</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Total of accepted hashes</b></td>
            <td><p id="ah">0</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>XMR Mined on this session</b></td>
            <td><p id="sm">0.00000000000000000000000</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" color="#FF0000" onclick="miner.stop();">Stop mining</button> </td>
            <td><button type="button" color="#00FF00"  onclick="miner.start();">Start mining</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But I would like to migrate this javascript that I have on my web site to a command line interface with node.js but unfortunately I could not find any documentation to convert it.

So I use the solution of **Vasan** but after coping the example script I get this error:

> C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop>node test.js module.js:544
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'coin-hive'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\test.js:1:80)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)

But it's installed because I can use this script:

> C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Roaming\npm\coin-hive

But while I doesn't want to use this I'm a bit blocked

Comment: Javascript is Javascript, wether it runs in the browser or in node. You don't need to "convert" anything. So, what's your problem?

Comment: how does I include this script: https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js

Comment: Using this NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/coin-hive

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What parts do you think you need to convert?

Comment: Off the question, do a bit of a calculation concerning your electricity bill and the sheer hash rate that you'll achieve. Just a tip.

Comment: @MilanVelebit I have a hunch that this is not intended to run on the OP's machine at all, but will be deployed to unsuspecting customers to drive up *their* electricity bill.

Comment: It seems you have the `coin-hive` package installed globally. You can either tell node to consider global modules when importing (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders), or install `coin-hive` locally. But you will hit other problems – for example the `window` and `documents` objects will be undefined in Node, unless you mock them somehow.

Comment: In your node project do `npm install coin-hive --save` (ignore `--save` if you have it as dependency already)

Answer (score 0):

So I sovled I by doing

> npm install coin-hive

And now it's working correctly